# How to avoir IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: when running r.reclass from QGIS not GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I run `r.reclass` from QGIS process toolbox (ie it works fine if i run from GRASS) and get this error :

```
2017-01-26T12:25:14 2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
                self.processAlgorithm(progress)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 274, in processAlgorithm
                func(self)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\ext\r_reclass.py", line 45, in processCommand
                with open(tempRulesName, "w") as tempRules:
            IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'tmp1485429914724
```

The same process works fine in  GRASS.

I have no admin issue / access in windows and my user is administrator

Comment: Make sure the raster name is less than 13 characters or try saving it on a different directory.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in "Processing", in the file r_reclass.py. The path to the rules file must be missing, hence it is not found and fails.

I have created a bug report at http://hub.qgis.org/issues/16128

Comment: Have exactly same issue on mac. Is it possible to fix it with the new file r_reclass.py ? where i have to put it ?

Comment: I think that QGIS 2.18.3 or newer will contain the fix.

Comment: Running into the exact same error with QGIS.2.18.15, is there any possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had this problem with the mosaic module from SAGA. I tried it with QGIS 2.14 and 2.18 fresh installation on windows 7. First I couldn't even locate the mentioned .bat files myself, so I figured it might have something to do with user profiles. Running the program as administrator didn't work. I realised the files might be hidden and that could be the reason. I un-hid the folder name c:\user\myname\ and all folders and files in the user\myname.qgis2 folder (including sub levels), and.... (to my surprise)... it worked.